# Python 3.6v range() function won't execute

Tags: python, for-loop, reverse

```
def fn():
  theList = []
  for rev in range(5, 0, -1):
    theList.append(rev)
    print(theList)

fn()
```

I don't understand, why this won't execute? 
My goal is to print something like this

```
[5,4,3,2,1,0]
[4,3,2,1,0]
[3,2,1,0]
[2,1,0]
[1,0]
[0]
```

Edit 1. Okey i added the comma(,) but the result is this

```
[5]
[5, 4]
[5, 4, 3]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Which is not what i am looking for

Comment: You're missing a comma in your `range` call. Also, your code won't run because it is not properly indented.

Comment: Why isn't that what you looking for? Seems like it's doing what it should

Comment: @cinico, trying to make reverse stairs, so i wanted the list to start like [5,4,3....], [4,3,2] etc

Comment: @Bokchee88 You should add that explanation to your question. It's impossible to infer what you were trying to do otherwise. What you wrote, creates a range from 5 to 1. Then, it iterates over each element of that range. Each time the cycle runs, it appends the next element to theList. So, it's normal that it produces what you see as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your output like this:

```
def fn():
    theList = list(range(5, -1, -1))
    for idx in range(len(theList)):
        print(theList[idx:])
fn()
```

Output:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
[1, 0]
[0]
```

Your code is using the wrong approach. Basically, your output shows that the list is full initially and goes on popping one element from the left on each iteration. Your approach starts with an empty list and adds an element on each iteration.

Also, `range(5, 0, -1)` is not the list you think it is. This is because the range function ignores the end value which is 0 here.

If you did this `list(range(5, 0, -1))`, you'd get `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` which obviously doesn't contain 0. So, to get the list you want, you'd have to do `list(range(5, -1, -1))` like in the code above.

Comment: It worked, could you explain why my code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

1)There is a typo in your function:

```
for rev in range(5, 0, -1):
```

2) you need to use your rev:

```
for rev in range(5, -1, -1):
    print(range(rev,-1,-1))
```